# how to update a column in my table by procedure in plsql using for loop?

Tags: plsql

i was written  a code to without for loop,please provide me solution to update it by for loop,create or replace procedure PR_UPDATETBEMP(COMM IN NUMBER) AS

```
begin
  UPDATE XX_TBEMP
  SET COMM=SAL*.05
  WHERE SAL BETWEEN 80000 AND 99999;
end PR_UPDATETBEMP;
```

Comment: Could You provide your table structure? columns etc.

Comment: Why would you want to do this in a loop? The single update statement you have already updates all the rows in one go and is going to be more performant than looping through a cursor and updating the data a row at a time.

Comment: ENO NUMBER(3) Y  
ENAME VARCHAR2(35)   
HIREDATE DATE   
SAL NUMBER(6)   
EXPR NUMBER(3)   
DEPTNO NUMBER(3)   
JOB VARCHAR2(20)   
COMM NUMBER(10)

Comment: that is my table structure,i that "COMM" column doesn't having any values,i want to add the values based on the "SAL" column by using procedure

Comment: ENO NUMBER(3)   
ENAME VARCHAR2(35)   
HIREDATE DATE   
SAL NUMBER(6)   
EXPR NUMBER(3)   
DEPTNO NUMBER(3)   
JOB VARCHAR2(20)   
COMM NUMBER(10)

that is my table structure,i that "COMM" column doesn't having any values,i want to add the values based on the "SAL" column by using procedure

Comment: i want update  multiple rows,please help me to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace PACKAGE XX_UPDATETBEMP AS
PROCEDURE XX_UPDATECOMM;
end XX_UPDATETBEMP;

create or replace PACKAGEBODY XX_UPDATETBEMP  AS 
PROCEDURE XX_UPDATECOMM IS
CURSOR C_TBEMP IS SELECT * FROM XX_TBEMP;
R_TBEMP C_TBEMP%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN

FOR SAL IN C_TBEMP
LOOP
UPDATE XX_TBEMP
      SET COMM        =  sal * 0.2 where SAL BETWEEN 30000 AND 49999;
      UPDATE XX_TBEMP
      SET COMM        = sal * 0.15 where SAL BETWEEN 50000 AND 79999;
      UPDATE XX_TBEMP
      SET COMM        = sal * 0.1  where SAL BETWEEN 80000 and 99999;
END LOOP;
END XX_UPDATECOMM;
END XX_UPDATETBEMP;
```